# Any alternative way to populate real time content in webpage other than jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

**Background:**
I have a webpage that lists latest 30 tweets from twitter. But every time I am calling jQuery ajax function to get the latest tweets. But this will be kinda overload to server and bandwidth issue I think.

I need an alternative solution for this . Is that possible with any other method

I am not sticking with jquery all the time, if php can do that ,great its enough. But how the client side will manage the refreshing the content

Comment: Other methods rather than using ajax, or other methods of using ajax? (which is regular javascript, you don't need jquery for that; it just makes things easier, that's all)

Comment: What kinda of alternative do you want? Just load less tweets, or update it less often accordingly, or increase the time for updates.

Comment: you can do is cache the results and display them from cache itself until and unless there is any change in the list which was loaded..

Comment: You'll have server and bandwidth issues with any method you use. But this kind of polling sounds rather harmless. What kind of visitor numbers do you have?

Comment: Hi all I've edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not related to jQuery, jQuery is merely a client-side javascript library.

If you don't want to do ajax request all the time, look into Websockets and/or longpolling techniques. This is how, for example, facebook implements its chat.

Interesting page: [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

Good luck!